# If an open, continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is one-to-one on a set of bounded complement, is $f$ one-to-one everywhere?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

An answer to the question would be nice, but what I want most is a list of books or principles to help resolve questions like this myself.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, please define what a co-bounded set is.